# Alternatives to GRE for multicast over MPLS?

Tags: mpls, multicast, gre, hp

I have an application that requires multicast across our MPLS WAN, and had been using GRE tunnels to facilitate this until recently when I replaced some aging edge routers with HP L3 switches. To my dismay it appears that these switches (Procurve E3800-24G-2SFP+) do not offer GRE in any way.

(I didn't source them, Layer 8 got a 2-for-1 deal from a fast talking reseller!)

Are there any alternatives for tunneling multicast across MPLS? Our WAN provider isn't likely to add support for mBGP just for me. :)

Comment: What kind of service is your WAN? Is it just point-to-point between your MPLS devices? Or are you the CE of their L3 MPLS VPN service?

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified that. It's a full mesh L3 MPLS VPN service.

Comment: Quite many support multicast in L3 MPLS VPN service, either NG-MVPN or RFC6037, I would confirm first that this is not possible.

Comment: It's been confirmed, the provider will not allow multicast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a router.

The HP 2520G is a Layer 2 managed switch, and has no Layer 3 capabilities.
This is highlighted in the [features tab](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/networking/products/switches/HP_2520_Switch_Series/index.aspx#tab=TAB2) on hp.com and in the [2520G feature support matrix](http://bizsupport2.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c03460274/c03460274.pdf)

If you're not able to get funding for a router, maybe you could power up a Vyatta VM at the ProCurve site?

Comment: Had the wrong model of switch in the original question. These are actually E3800-24G-2SFP+ Layer 3 managed switches.

Answer (score 0):

For GRE support , HP has the exH3C based A5800 switches (take a look at the release notes: https://h10145.www1.hp.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=JC103A). The E3800 is based upon HP´s "old" Procurve design. You can get the A5800 series pretty cheap as refurbished "HP Renew" with HP warranty left.